# Hiding QGIS toolbars through python code?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-2.6

```
for eg.
iface.rasterToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

this works from python console of QGIS 2.6.1 but does not work from plugin code.

Comment: how are you using the command? I've tested it with my plugin with `self.iface.rasterToolBar().setVisible(False)` and it worked fine

Comment: self.iface.rasterToolBar().setVisible(False)     same as this in initgui method

Comment: are there reasons why you can't upgrade to a newer version? 2.14 is the LTR while 2.18 is the current version

Comment: yeah i need to use 2.6.1

Comment: @drama - Are you receiving any errors? Did you try `self.qgis.utils.iface.rasterToolBar().setVisible(False)`?

Comment: no errors but not working too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one worked!

```
    for x in self.iface.rasterToolBar().actions():
        #x.setEnabled(False)
         x.setVisible(False)
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Does this actually hide the toolbar or just the icons inside it?

Comment: yes @Joseph icon is just a variable i have used